# How to find empty port to start WCF web ServiceHost

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking, port

How can I determine an un-used port to start a WCF ServiceHost to host a localhost web server on?

I'm currently starting my service up statically on http://localhost:XXXX where XXXX is a static value in my code.

I'd like to replace the XXXX with a GetUnusedPort() call...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I could find was the try until you find an open one option...

http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/c-how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-in-use-371148.html

```
    public static bool TryPortNumber(int port)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, port)))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException error)
        {
            if (error.SocketErrorCode == System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse /* check this is the one you get */ )
                return false;
            /* unexpected error that we DON'T have handling for here */
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not let the user choose which port they want to host the service on? For example, add a value to your application's configuration file that gets passed to your ServiceHost. You could also try randomly generating a port number and test to see if it's open, then repeat the process if another application is already using it.

Comment: Any number of reasons. He may be starting one or more dynamically-generated services which are not known about in advance and therefore cannot be individually configured.